# How to use MAX with additional criteria

Tags: sql, db2

A) When goods are sold, a table will record an “O” in column ID & a “N” in column TYPE:-

```
SKU      ID  TYPE  NR
-------------------------
HAB1122  O   N     201211
```

B) When goods are returned, a table will record an “O” in column ID & a “R” in column TYPE:-

```
SKU      ID  TYPE  NR
-------------------------
HAB1122  O   R     201223
```

Scenario 1

Goods were sold & returned later. It was sold subsequently:-

```
SKU      ID  TYPE  NR
-------------------------
HAB1122  O   N     201211
HAB1122  O   R     201223
HAB1122  O   N     201245
HAB2233  O   N     201263
HAB3344  O   N     201303
HAB3344  O   R     201341
```

Using SQL:-

```
Select SKU, max(NR) 
from tableA
where SKU like ‘HAB%’ and ID = ‘O’
group by SKU
```

Results:-

```
SKU       NR
----------------
HAB1122   201245
HAB2233   201263
HAB3344   201341
```

This is the correct result as I wish to track down the last NR of the goods sold whether the goods are sold or returned.

If I wish to track down the last NR of goods with status sold only, the expected results should be:-

```
SKU      NR
---------------
HAB1122  201245
HAB2233  201263
```

HAB3344 is not considered as the goods are returned & not sold subsequently.

How should I change the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select   SKU, max(NR)
from     TABLEA T1
where    SKU like 'HAB%' and ID = 'O'
group by SKU
having   max(NR) <> (select nvl(max(NR), 0)
                     from   TABLEA T2
                     where  T1.SKU = T2.SKU and T2.type = 'R');
```

This is using Oracle. You didn't indicate your system so the `having` may not work specifically on yours but an equivalent will.

Comment: I'm using DB2. It prompted an error:-  NVL in *LIBL type *N not found.

Comment: I believe in DB2 you use `coalesce` instead of `nvl`. Give that a go.

Comment: I hv amended & executed the SQL statement. It's taking way too long to process the data. In fact, it's still running. Prior to this, it takes less than 2 minutes to generate the results.

Comment: Check your indexes, you should have one at least on SKU.

Comment: Found it. It's so much better now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA AS T1
WHERE SKU like ‘HAB%’ and ID = ‘O’ AND T1.[TYPE] = 'N'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tableA AS T2
    WHERE T2.SKU = T1.SKU
    AND T2.NR > T1.NR
    AND ID = ‘O’
)
```

Results:

```
SKU        ID   TYPE NR
---------- ---- ---- -----------
HAB1122    O    N    201245
HAB2233    O    N    201263
```

From a quick google search, DB2 appears to support Window Functions and CTE's. I can say that for at least SQL Server, window functions perform better in this scenario:

`ROW_NUMBER()`: http://forums.devshed.com/db2-development-114/rownumber-over-169453.html

CTE's: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/samples/clp/s-cte-db2.htm

Window Functions Approach:

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT T1.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY NR DESC) AS RN
    FROM tableA AS T1 
    WHERE ID = ‘O’
)
SELECT T.SKU, T.NR
FROM T 
WHERE RN = 1 AND SKU like ‘HAB%’ AND T1.[TYPE] = 'N';
```

Comment: I tried the 1st option. It's taking way too long to process the data. In fact, it's still running. Prior to this, it takes less than 2 minutes to generate the results. With option 2, i rcv'd the following error msg:- Error: SQL5001 - Column qualifier or table T1 undefined. (State:S1000, Native Code: FFFFEC77)

Comment: @Bob - for your error - use `tableA` instead of `@myTable` (I think). I will update my answer to match your tables.

Comment: Your `ROW_NUMBER()` solution may not work as expected. If an ID other than `'O'` happens to have the greatest `NR` value per some `SKU`, your query will not return that `SKU`, because neither of the `O` rows will be ranked as `1`, while the OP's intention seems to be to disregard the fact that other (non-`O`) IDs might come ‘after’ `O`s.

Comment: @Bob - all solutions (that work) will perform best with an index on key columns SKU, NR - in that order.

Comment: @AndriyM - that is not how I understood the problem... see his statement "If I wish to track down the last NR of goods with status sold only, the expected results should be" where he excludes `HAB3344` because the last `NR` is type `R`

Comment: Ah, yes, but I am not talking about `TYPE`, I'm talking about `ID`. They say little about `ID` and nothing about other values than `'O'`, in particular, but the `ID = 'O'` filter suggests there *may* be other values. The OP is filtering on `ID`, *then* trying to pick the latest `NR` per `SKU` if it is type `'N'`. In other words, the OP seems to want to return the latest `NR` if it's type `'N'` *for `ID = 'O'`*, but you are returning latest `NR` if it's type `'N'` and *if `ID = 'O'`*.

Comment: @AndriyM - good point, i believe you are correct. I modified my solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

`Select SKU, max(NR) from tableA where SKU like 'HAB%' and ID = 'O' and TYPE = 'N' group by SKU`?

Comment: No, it will extract HAB1122 (201245), HAB2233 (201263) & HAB3344 (201303). HAB3344 shd not be there as the goods are still in inventory. I just need to track items which are sold ie no longer in the inventory.

Comment: Edited (formatted) question makes it much easier to see. John Doyle answer seems to be right; and try to format your questions better next time.

Answer (score 0):

If your database system supports ranking functions, like `ROW_NUMBER()`, you could try the following:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY NR DESC) AS RNK
  FROM atable
  WHERE SKU LIKE 'HAB%'
    AND ID = 'O'
)
SELECT
  SKU,
  NR
FROM ranked
WHERE TYPE = 'N'
  AND RNK = 1
```

Comment: Error: SQL0104 - Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: FROM INTO. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF98)

Comment: @Bob: I think the token itself in your comment was ‘eaten’ by the parser. Please try to re-post the message enclosing it in backticks (`\``). Or just tell me what token it was.

Comment: Token "," was not valid. Valid tokens: FROM INTO. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF98)

Comment: @Bob: Ah, I see, you mean a comma was the token that was invalid, thanks. But it's very puzzling, I can't imagine which of the two commas in my query could be the offending one and why.